# adding two sparse matrix using operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, sparse-matrix

I am Developing an ADT for sparse matrix on C++(using Visual C++ 2012)

Here is my Class definition :

The class Class includes an Array of cell (every cell includes a row number , a column number and a none zero value)

Edit:I think the problem most be with copy constructor , so I have add the constructor here:

```
    class Sparce
{

    friend std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream& os, Sparce &sprc);

    Cell * cells;
    int row;
    int col;
    int value;


public:
    Sparce(int ** a , int r, int c);

    Sparce( const Sparce & a )
{
    cells = new Cell[a.value];
    setRow(a.row);
    setCol(a.col);
    setValue(a.value);


    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
    {
        cells[i].setCell(a.cells[i].getRow(),a.cells[i].getCol(),a.cells[i].getValue());
    }

}

    Sparce (int r , int c , int val);

    ~Sparce(void);

    int getRow();
    int getCol();
    int getValue();

    void setRow(int r);
    void setCol(int c);
    void setValue(int v);

    int getRowX(int i);
    int getRowY(int i);
    int getRowValue(int i);


    Sparce operator+ (Sparce sp2);
};
```

And Cell definition is:

```
class Cell
{
public:
Cell(int r , int c , int v);
Cell();

int getRow();
int getCol();
int getValue();

void setCell(int r , int c , int v);
void setRow(int r);
void setCol(int c);
void setValue(int v);

private:
int row;
int col;
int value;
};
```

It seems my + operator is not working and I got a run time error on return line in operator:

```
Sparce Sparce::operator+ (Sparce sp2)
{
    if(getRow() != sp2.getRow() || getCol() != sp2.getCol())
        throw std::exception("For adding to array most have same rows and coloumns");


    int k1 = 0 , k2 = 0 , k3 = 0;
    //counting number of none zero value for result
    while (k1 < getRow() && k2<sp2.getRow())
    {
        if(getRowX(k1) < sp2.getRowX(k2))
        {
            k1++;
            k3++;
        }
        else if(getRowX(k1) > sp2.getRowX(k2)) 
        {
            k2++;
            k3++;
        }
        else if(getRowX(k1) == sp2.getRowX(k2)) 
        {
            if (getRowY(k1) < sp2.getRowY(k2))
            {
                k1++;
                k3++;
            }
            else if(getRowY(k1) > sp2.getRowY(k2)) 
            {
                k2++;
                k3++;
            }
            else if(getRowX(k1) == sp2.getRowX(k2)) 
            {
                k1++;
                k2++;
                k3++;
            }
        }
    }//while

    while(k1<getValue())
    {
        k1++;
        k3++;
    }

    while(k2<sp2.getValue())
    {
        k2++;
        k3++;
    }
    //end counting

    k3--;//we will count one extra ++ , so We should reduce it.when i comment this line there will be no run time error and correct answer but an extra line in result
    Sparce res(getRow(),getCol(),k3);

    k1 = 0;
    k2 = 0;
    k3 = 0;

    while (k1 < getRow() && k2<sp2.getRow())
    {
        if(getRowX(k1) < sp2.getRowX(k2)) 
        {
            res.cells[k3].setCell(getRowX(k1),getRowY(k1),getRowValue(k1));
            k1++;
            k3++;
        }
        else if(getRowX(k1) > sp2.getRowX(k2)) 
        {
            res.cells[k3].setCell(sp2.getRowX(k2),sp2.getRowY(k2),sp2.getRowValue(k2));
            k2++;
            k3++;
        }
        else if(getRowX(k1) == sp2.getRowX(k2)) 
        {
            if (getRowY(k1) < sp2.getRowY(k2))
            {
                res.cells[k3].setCell(getRowX(k1),getRowY(k1),getRowValue(k1));
                k1++;
                k3++;
            }
            else if(getRowY(k1) > sp2.getRowY(k2)) 
            {
                res.cells[k3].setCell(sp2.getRowX(k2),sp2.getRowY(k2),sp2.getRowValue(k2));
                k2++;
                k3++;
            }
            else if(getRowX(k1) == sp2.getRowX(k2)) 
            {
                res.cells[k3].setCell(sp2.getRowX(k2),sp2.getRowY(k2),getRowValue(k1)+sp2.getRowValue(k2));
                k1++;
                k2++;
                k3++;
            }
        }
    }//while

    while(k1<getValue())
    {
        res.cells[k3].setCell(getRowX(k1),getRowY(k1),getRowValue(k1));
        k1++;
        k3++;
    }

    while(k2<sp2.getValue())
    {
        res.cells[k3].setCell(sp2.getRowX(k2),sp2.getRowY(k2),sp2.getRowValue(k2));
        k2++;
        k3++;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Edit : When I comment last k3-- in my code (i have add a comment on that line) problem will be solved , but result will have one extra line

What Can be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: For a start you might do well to correct the spelling of sparse

Comment: As for your question, what format are you using to store the matrices? And what operations do you plan to implement?

Comment: Can you describe your algorithm in 1000000 words or less? And how can you add two sparse matrices without referencing a single Cell -- or allocating any either? What are all those k's?

Comment: added a few more information to post about how my class stores data

Comment: Hint: the classic sparse array is implemented as a linked list of Row objects; a Row contains a row number and a linked list of Cells; a Cell contains a column number and a value. Operator+() should be less than 20 lines of code.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill , So why my code is so difficult? , what will be that code?

Comment: Find a new thing about counting , Post edited .....

Comment: I'm trying to refactor this and I think the code is trying to implement two completely different ideas. You're using "row" both as the number of rows in the matrix and the number of cells in the array. And why aren't you using for-loops?

Comment: @leewangzhong , the result is correct , so there is no problem with algorithm , Some thing with operator or copy constructor must be wrong

Comment: Your operator+'s algorithm can't possibly be correct. It uses getRow() to get the size of the array, and then uses getValue() later on to get the size. The only way you would get it right is by coincidence, if the number of rows is equal to the number of cells. (By the way, your small while loops above "//end counting" should be replaced by subtractions and additions.)

Comment: I recommend you rename your variables in the matrix class "rows", "cols", and "length"/"size"/otherthing: the number of rows, the number of columns, and the number of non-zero entries. Also, don't have a public set method for the number of entries. You should be setting it directly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40822/discussion-between-leewangzhong-and-arashdn)

Comment: What does the destructor look like?

Comment: @leewangzhong , my destructor has just one command : delete[] cells;

Answer (score 0):

You declare the copy constructor as taking a non-const reference. Copy constructor should usually take const reference. It's possible that *something* is happening where operator+ is being called that makes the compiler uses the default const-ref copy constructor (which shallow-copies the pointer).

It's also possible that your copy constructor or destructor is not written properly.

Tip: Have you considered using std::vector to hold your array? Then you don't have to worry about taking care of the pointer.

Comment: Thanks for reply , I tried `Sparce( const Sparce &  a );` but nothing changed ......

Comment: While none of these things are truly *wrong*, per se, they're not *right* either. For example, the parameter isn't a non-const reference -- it's by value. There's your shallow copy right there. But the real problem is a horribly wrong data structure, and a horribly wrong algorithm.

Comment: If it's at the return, then it's probably either the copy constructor or the destructor. Can you post them?

Comment: @Ernest The parameter of the _copy ctor_ is non-const ref. And the question is about the runtime error.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I meant by not wrong, but not right. If the parameter to operator+() were correct, the copy ctor question would be moot.

Comment: I was pointing out that the copy constructor might have been failing at return (it's return-by-copy).

Comment: I also think the problem is with copy constructor , So I edited the post and added my copy constructor